# Fatal error PHP y no se como solucionarlo

Tags: php, mysql

Estaba haciendo un trabajo en PHP y me salió este error y la verdad no se como solucionarlo, espero puedan ayudarme. He de decir que ya verifiqué los datos con la base de datos de MySQL y tengo todo bien, los nombres de las variables si están como deberían.

```
<?php

class Datos_model {
    private $db;
    private $datos;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = Conectar::conexion();
        $this->datos = array();
    }

    public function get_datos(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos";
        $resultado = $this->db->query($sql);
        while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            $this->datos[] = $row;
        }
        return $this->datos;
    }

    public function insertar($cedula, $nombre, $apellido, $fecha_nacimiento, $usuario, $clave){
        $resultado = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO datos (cedula, nombre, apellido, fecha nacimiento, usuario, clave) VALUES ('$cedula', '$nombre', '$apellido', '$fecha_nacimiento', '$usuario', '$clave')");

    }
}
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'nacimiento, usuario, clave) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '')' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\T1\modelo\DatosModel.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\T1\modelo\DatosModel.php(22): mysqli->query('INSERT INTO dat...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\T1\control\Datos.php(30): Datos_model->insertar('', '', '', '', '', '') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\T1\core\routes.php(18): DatosController->guarda() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\T1\index.php(12): cargarAccion(Object(DatosController), 'guarda') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\T1\modelo\DatosModel.php on line 22

Comment: El espacio `fecha nacimiento`

Comment: el codigo de error te esta solucionando todo, debes fijarte en la sintaxis de la consulta, y en fecha nacimiento falta un guion bajo me parece. No estoy seguro pero creo que el primer parentesis donde colocas los nombres de las columnas no es necesario, al menos en mi caso no lo utilizo.

Comment: Cuando hago eso me da otro error diciendo que no se reconoce la columna "fecha_nacimiento" en "field list"

Comment: @BetaM ahora me da este error                                                         
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\T1\modelo\DatosModel.php on line 22

Comment: Se puede usar espacios en blanco en los nombres de tablas / columnas, pero en ese caso debes usar [comillas invertidas (backticks)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)  para escribir esas columnas en las instrucciones SQL. Pero el que se *pueda* no significa que se *deba* hacer. Es mejor, como te han sugerido, usar guión bajo para separar y no el espacio en blanco.

Comment: ponele `AUTO_INCREMENT` a la primary key que al no estar en el insert le asigna 0 siempre

Comment: @aloMalbarez loca cosa es donde tengo el primary key? porque no lo veo jeje

Comment: la tabla datos debe tener un campo designado como PRIMARY KEY clave primaria/principal, usualmente se le llama `id` pero puede tener otro nombre fijate en la definicion de la tabla si usas phpmyadmin al editar la definición hay un checkbox ( puede decir Auto Increment o AI ) si es por linea de comandos hay que hacer un ALTER TABLE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html